# restrict image dimension in react-dropzone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dropzone

I am using react-dropzone for image upload. Everything is working fine. Validation for image size is also working fine. But I could not check the dimension for image. I want to validate the image's width and height to enforce user to upload the image in between those specified width and height. I tried `image.addEventListener('load')` but this is not working.

Here is what I have done

```
export const UploadField = ({ preview, label, uploadProps, ...props }) => {
  const {
    input: { onChange },
    disabled
  } = props;

  const {
    isDragActive,
    getRootProps,
    getInputProps,
    isDragReject,
    rejectedFiles
  } = useDropzone({
    onDrop: files => {
      onChange(
        files.map(file => {
          const image = new Image();
          image.addEventListener("load", () => {
            console.log("image", image);
          });
          return Object.assign(file, {
            preview: URL.createObjectURL(file)
          });
        })
      );
    },
    ...uploadProps
  });

  const isFileTooLarge =
    rejectedFiles.length > 0 && rejectedFiles[0].size > uploadProps.maxSize;

  const files = props.input.value;

  if (disabled) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <>
      {label && <Label>{label}</Label>}
      <DropzoneContainer {...getRootProps()}>
        <input {...getInputProps()} />
        {!isDragActive && "Click here or drop a file to upload!"}
        {isDragActive && !isDragReject && "Drop it like it's hot!"}
        {isDragReject && "File type not accepted, sorry!"}
        {isFileTooLarge && (
          <div className="text-danger mt-2">File is too large.</div>
        )}
      </DropzoneContainer>
      <div>
        {files && files !== undefined ? (
          <>
            <Preview files={files} isLocal />
          </>
        ) : (
          <Preview files={preview} isLocal={false} />
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default UploadField;

UploadField.defaultProps = {
  uploadProps: {
    accept: "image/*",
    multiple: false,
    minSize: 0,
    maxSize: 5242880
  }
};

const DropzoneContainer = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  padding: 14px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border-color: ${props => getColor(props)};
  border-style: dashed;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  color: #bdbdbd;
  outline: none;
  transition: border 0.24s ease-in-out;
`;

const getColor = props => {
  if (props.isDragAccept) {
    return "#00e676";
  }
  if (props.isDragReject) {
    return "#ff1744";
  }
  if (props.isDragActive) {
    return "#2196f3";
  }
  return "#eeeeee";
};
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You never set the `src` for the image so your event handler never fires. Try setting `image.src = URL.createObjectURL(file)`. Once the file loads, your 'load' handler will fire.

Try changing the contents of your `onDrop` callback to include this:

```js
const filteredImages = [];
let counter = 0;

files.map(file => {
    const image = new Image();
    image.addEventListener('load', () => {
        console.log(`${image.width}x${image.height}`)

        // only select images within width/height limits
        if (image.width < WIDTH_LIM && image.height < HEIGHT_LIM) {
            filteredImages.push(image)
        }

        // increment counter for each image we go through
        counter += 1;

        // if we have gone through all the files, handle the ones that
        // made it through the filter using `handleImages` function
        if (counter === files.length) handleImages(filteredImages);
    });
    image.src = URL.createObjectURL(file)
})
```

Comment: this one worked. But problem is even if the uploaded image dimension does not match with the standard dimension that is mentioned in the condition, the image gets uploaded.

Comment: I see. You may have to restructure your function a little. Give me a moment, I will edit my answer with a solution

Comment: please see my edit @Serenity, although you may need to restructure some of your original code.

Comment: this single & operator throwing an error in nextjs code base instead of that use two && 
```if (image.width < WIDTH_LIM && image.height < HEIGHT_LIM) { filteredImages.push(image) }```

Comment: @aseladaskon that's a good catch, thanks. Updated

Comment: I don't know why, but with this code, I can't call `removeFile(file)` function...I tried also with a `useEffect` boolean, It seems I can't remove the file

Answer (score 9):

If you want to validate dimensions before `onDrop`, you can use `getFilesFromEvent` and `validator` callbacks like below.

**Pros**
As with errors such as maxSize and accept, you can get files that are stuck in validation for dimention from `rejectedFiles`.

**Cons**
f you are using typescript, you have to eliminate the type error with any type.

```js
const {
    isDragActive,
    getRootProps,
    getInputProps,
    isDragReject,
    rejectedFiles
  } = useDropzone({
    getFilesFromEvent: async (event) => {
      const files = event.target.files || event.dataTransfer.files
      const promises = []
      for (let index = 0; index < files.length; index++) {
        const file = files[index]
        const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const image = new Image()
          let url: string
          image.onload = function () {
            file.width = image.width
            file.height = image.height
            resolve(file)
          }
          url = URL.createObjectURL(file)
          image.src = url
        })
        promises.push(promise)
      }
      return await Promise.all(promises)
    },
    validator: (file) => {
      // You can access width/height properties
      if(file.width < MIN_WIDTH) {
        return {
          code: "small-width",
          message: `Image width must be greater than ${MIN_WIDTH}`,
        }
      }
      return null
    }

  });
```

Comment: thank you so much for taking the time to document this. Very helpful solution.